# WCF elf Hosted Service in Windows Application

Tags: rest, wcf, windows, self-hosting

I have created a sample desktop application to check self hosted REST service in windows application. Here is my samples

```
public class PayMentService : IPayMentService
{
    public string PayBill()
    {
        return "Transaction having PayId 12 was successful";
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IPayMentService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/PayBill", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string PayBill();

}
```

And my configuration file is like

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="JsonBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="SelfHostedWCFService.WCFService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="JsonBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
          contract="SelfHostedWCFService.IWCFService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8785" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="SelfHostedWCFService.WCFCheck">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SelfHostedWCFService.IWCFCheck">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/SelfHostedWCFService/WCFCheck/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="SelfHostedWCFService.PayMentService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SelfHostedWCFService.IPayMentService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/SelfHostedWCFService/PayMentService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And i hosted it to a configured URL like

```
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SelfHostedWCFService.PayMentService));
        host.Open();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

I tried to call my service by the help of the URL http://localhost:8785/service/PayMentService/PayBill. But it failed. I know service is up and running and i can catch my request in my PayMentService constructor but i can't execute my PayBill() function. I tried different options but nothing works.Can anyone give some advice..?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to call my service by the help of the URL http://localhost:8785/service/PayMentService/PayBill. But it failed.
You need to enable metadata discovery which is turned off by default.You are there almost ,the missing one is

Name the meta service behavior implementaion .

```
 <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="metadataDiscovery">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
```

Add that to your Payment service.

```
 <service name="SelfHostedWCFService.PayMentService" behaviorConfiguration="metadataDiscovery">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SelfHostedWCFService.IPayMentService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Now you can browse the wsdl,http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/SelfHostedWCFService/PayMentService/ . Similarly add the behavior tag configuration to all your service name tags.

You have also explained that Constructor is hit in debug mode,there are few things missing in your code.

```
 <endpointBehaviors>    
        <behavior name="JsonBehavior">   
          <webHttp/>    
        </behavior>    
      </endpointBehaviors>   

    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" 
contract="PayMentRESTService.IPayMentService" behaviorConfiguration="JsonBehavior">
```

Refer http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/creating-wcf-rest-service/ for in detail.